# Why is my alert displayed twice?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uialertview

in my app I check the current connection status to my website and the network status on app startup:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
       selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
       name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
[internetReach startNotifier];

hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.de"] 
              retain];
[hostReach startNotifier];

[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:internetReach];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:hostReach];

//....

-(void)reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: curReach];
}
```

In my `updateInterfaceWithReachability` I want to show an alert if a connection to the website cannot be established.

My problem is that the alert is displayed twice, so the first comes up and when I dismiss it the seconds is displayed:

```
if(curReach == hostReach){
        NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];

        if(netStatus != NotReachable){
            statusLabel.text = @"connected";
            [self setStatusColorGreen];
        }else{
            if(![internetReach connectionRequired]){
                statusLabel.text = @"not connected";
                compose.enabled = NO;
                [self doSMSFAlert];
                [self setStatusColorRed];
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I noticed now that I have a working host the alert is displayed too but it shouldn't. However the status is 'connected'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are doing two Reachability notification. Your first one is for the Internet in general. The second one is for a specific host. Why don't you just do the host Reachability only? That way you will only get one alert.

Comment: In your code above, I see two ivars. One is `internetReach and `hostReach`. I am saying you don't need both.

Comment: I removed the internetReach stuff, so now I get the alert but the status is connected so it seems that the code is running twice, first run gives the alert for not connected and the second says we are connected....strange. Maybe this is asynchrouns and the second run indicates that there is a response and the first run was request?

Comment: None of my app needs the Internet so I haven't done any Reachability coding. You will need to search the Reachability code and remove the alert that is displayed when connected.

Comment: actually I mean this [self doSMSFAlert]; , Reachability code itself has no alert

Comment: The if statement above the `[self doSMSFAlert]` is testing against the `internetReach` ivar. The if statement needs to be update to test against the `hostReach`.

Answer (score 1):

You are responding to a notification event. The event can be delivered as many times as the status changes and it is up to you to know if you already have responded or are responding to a similar status change. Some options are storing a boolean or checking if you alert view is currently up before attempting to display another.